# calling relation with a parameter in the view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

i know this has been asked alot , but none of the solution works for me as i want to use this in the view

i have 3 tables

```
Languages : id , title 
Blog : id 
BlogLanguage : blog_id , language_id , title , text
```

so when i list the blogs in the view , for each blog i want to show what languages has been stores for this Blog

basically i want to do something like this

```
$blogs = Blog::all();
$languages = Language::all();
return view('blog-index' , compact('blogs' ,'languages));
```

in the view

```
@foreach($blogs as $blog )

  id : {{$blog->id}} 
  @foreach($languages as $lang )
   {{$lang->title}} : {{ $lang->HasThisBlog($blog->id) ? 'yes' : 'no' }}
  @endforeach

@endforeach
```

here is what im stuck

```
{{ $lang->HasThisBlog($blog->id) ? 'yes' : 'no' }}
```

if i can have this relation in the Language model

```
function HasThisBlog($id){
 return $this->hasOne(BlogLanguage::class )->where('blog_id' , $id ) ;
}
```

of course this doesn't work and gives me some weird object like

```
HasOne {#706 ▼
  #foreignKey: "blog_languages.language_id"
  #localKey: "id"
  #query: Builder {#705 ▶}
  #parent: Language {#560 ▶}
  #related: BlogLanguage {#667 ▶}
  #withDefault: null
}
```

Comment: You're defining a `hasOne` relationship in the model but using a pivot table in your migrations. Can your `Blog` have multiple `Languages` or just one?

Comment: @Unflux blog has multiple languages , basically website has like 10 language but the operator may enter 2 or 3 and leave the rest  ... i've defined hasOne becuz im checking for a single blog if it has a language or not so it has 1 on 1 relation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to define a relation on you Blog model. As you already have pivot table for the following relationships

**Blog belongsToMany Language(s)**

**Language belongsToMany Blog(s)**

```php
class Blog extends Model
{
    public function languages()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Language::class);
    }

    //....other code of the class
}

class Language extends Model
{
    public function blogs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Blog::class);
    }

    //... other code of the class
}
```

Then in blade view

```
@foreach($blogs as $blog)

    <p>{{ $blog->id }}</p>

    @foreach($languages as $language)
        <p>{{ $language->title }}: {{ $blog->languages->contains('id', $language->id) ? 'Yes' : 'No' }}</p>
    @endforeach

@endforeach
```